# Importing multiple scss files with /* fails with vue webpack

Tags: webpack, sass

I have a `main.scss` when I import multiple partials with:

```
// Partials
@import "partials/*"
```

Sadly, this results in a build failure:

```
./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-5ef48958","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/app.vue
Module build failed: 
@import "partials/*"
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: partials/*.
```

It seems multiple selector doesn't work. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
@import "partials/_all.scss"
```

and in `_all.scss`

include all .scss files needed

Comment: That's a workaround. And it would result in still having to maintain all the separate include references in `_all.scss`